# What is the replacement of EJB SessionContext object in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, spring-session, sessioncontext

I am migrating an EJB project to Spring boot project. I have successfully replaced other annotations to the spring annotation, but havving problem with SessionContext object.
My legacy code is bellow

```
@Resource
SessionContext sessionContext;
.....
if (some condition) {
    sessionContext.setRollbackOnly();
    return false;
}
```

For this code i am getting the following error

```
A component required a bean of type 'javax.ejb.SessionContext' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.ejb.SessionContext' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to use a few different functionalities.

**setRollbackOnly()**

Most often I have seen Session Context used for Rollbacks. In Spring, you can replace this with:

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

or annotate class with

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = MyException.class)
```

so you can throw your exception from class to cause rollback.

**getBusinessObject()**

The second most commonly used feature is method to load a business object so that I can, for example, create a new transaction within a same bean. In this case you can use Self-inject:

```
@Lazy private final AccountService self;
```

and annote method with @Transactional. This, of course, solves any other cases where you need to use the power of a proxy object.

Other functionality is provided by other classes in Spring, but I think that these two are the most commonly used in the Java EE world and when migrating, one will look to replace them in Spring.

Comment: The class i am editing doesnt contain any ```@Transaction``` annotation, rather calls methods from other class which contains ```@Transaction``` annotation. Is it a concern?

Comment: I think it should be OK. The transaction is already activated by the previous method.